# Android application licence for just a period of time

Tags: android

We have developed an android application, and we would like that users could buy the application but just for a period of time, for example a year. Once the period has expired, they should buy the application again for a new period of time.

We have had a look to the Google information about "Application Licensing", but we haven't seen a licence for a period of time. When a user buys a application in "Google Play", he buys forever, so this is not a solution for us.

Is any "google api" to manage this scenario? Any idea about how we could develop this scenario?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

There is the recently incorporated concept of *in-app subscription* items. On this scenario, a user would get the application for free, and then pay for a subscription to access certain content for a given period of time.

Reference: [Subscriptions](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_subscriptions.html)

Comment: Thanks... I started reading about it yesterday, but I've a problem. It's not possible to test it in the emulator, and I don't have an android mobile with a "data plan". What can I do?

Comment: @Eduardo: I believe no market functionality can be tested with an emulator. If you have a real device then a data plan should not be needed, a wifi connection should be enough.

Comment: The problem is that in the office where I'm working there is not wifi connection. We are in an intranet behind a proxy. Thanks