# Subscription for android App

Tags: android, google-play-services

What I want to do is publish my app on Google Play.When the User will buy the app he/she has to pay the price initially.I want my app to be renewed after a certain period i.e monthly.If the period gets over the user will not be able to use the app.Any idea how to do it?Is in-app subscription for android app the solution for this?

Comment: We're here to provide help, support and answers on programming issues that have small, contained examples. Sorry but your question is pretty off topic.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018855/android-application-licence-for-just-a-period-of-time

Answer (score 0):

Please see this android developer guide for subscriptions.

From android docs

"A subscription is a product type offered in In-app Billing that lets you sell content, services, or features to users from inside your app with recurring **monthly or annual billing**. You can sell subscriptions to almost any type of digital content, from any type of app or game"

**User billing**

In the Developer Console, you can configure subscription products with automated recurring billing at either of two intervals:

**Monthly** — Google Play bills the customer’s Google Wallet account at the time of purchase and monthly subsequent to the purchase date (exact billing intervals can vary slightly over time)

**Annually** — Google Play bills the customer's Google Wallet account at the time of purchase and again on the same date in subsequent years

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html

Comment: Link only answers are not recommended as they can be changed and become dead links. Perhaps quote a bit of the text in future

Comment: If you edit your answer to include relevant quotes and various snippets that can be preserved if the link dies I'll up it you so it's not a negative.

Comment: What happens if the user uninstalls the app.Will the subscription remain active??

Comment: **App uninstallation** -  

When the user uninstalls an app that includes purchased subscriptions, the Play Store app will notify the user that there are active subscriptions. If the user chooses to continue with the uninstallation, the app is removed and the subscriptions remain active and recurring billing continues. The user can return to cancel the associated subscriptions at any time in the My Apps screen of the Play Store app. If the user chooses to cancel the uninstallation, the app and subscriptions remain as they were